# CakePHP - Auto logout after time limit of user being idle

Tags: cakephp, redirect, logout

I have set up a meta tag in my layout to ensure that the user is logged out after a set time if they remain idle.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600;url=http://www.example.com/users/logout/redirect:%2Fusers%2Faccount" />
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass the current URL (encoded) as a redirect parameter, so that when the logout action is called and redirects to the login page, the login page will know which page to redirect the user back to whatever they were doing when the system auto logged them out.

However, when the auto logout occurs, it redirects to `http://www.example.com/users/logout/redirect:%2Fusers%2Faccount` as expected, but I get a 404 error:

**/users/logout/redirect:/users/account** was not found

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why reinventing the wheel? set the idle time in `Session.timeout` inside the `core.php`, and use the Auth component to manage your login redirections. You dont need that meta in your layout

Comment: I wasn't aware of Session.timeout.  Now where would I get Auth to redirect back to the page the user was on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding at least, is that is not possible to achieve this using `urlencode` due to how the slashes will be translated and handled by Cake. I'm not sure on the specifics however!

One solution would be to use `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` instead on the URL.

You may be able to set up a route with some `regex` to handle the extra slashes correctly.

```
echo 'http://example.com/users/logout/redirect:' . base64_encode('users/account');
//http://example.com/users/logout/redirect:dXNlcnMvYWNjb3VudA==
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking of using base64 anyway, so I can pass the username to the login form as well and auto fill that field for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout in the core file.

To redirect after the login you need to add

```
$this->Auth->autoRedirect = true;
```

in the app_controller. (See [preparing to add auth](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1545/Preparing-to-Add-Auth) and [AuthComponent Class](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/auth-component))

The auth component will notice that the page you're trying to see is controlled. So after rendering the login page, it will store the page's url in session.
To test it, you can do a `print_r($_SESSION)` in the login view and you will see it under `$_SESSION['Auth']['redirect']`

And that's it =) Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it easier. I use Cake 3.2 but I think the old versions are same.

Config the routes info. In Cake 3.2 is in /config/routes.php

```
$routes->connect('/logout', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout']);
```

Now you will logout by access to URL http://domain.com/logout instead of http://domain.com/Users/logout.

Base on your meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600;/logout" />
```

Try it, it worked for me :D